# How to save data from website by using python + selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, selenium

I have written a script which is opening multiple tabs one by one and taking data from there. Now I am able to get data from the page but when writing in CSV file getting data as per below.

```
Bedrooms    Bathrooms   Super area  Floor   Status

3 See Dimensions    3 See Dimensions    2100    7 (Out of 23 Floors)    3 See Dimensions

Bedrooms    Bathrooms   Super area  Floor   Status

3 See Dimensions    3 See Dimensions    2100    7 (Out of 23 Floors)    3 See Dimensions

Bedrooms    Bathrooms   Super area  Floor   Status

1   1   520 4 (Out of 40 Floors)    1

Bedrooms    Bathrooms   Super area  Floor   Status

3 See Dimensions    3 See Dimensions    2100    7 (Out of 23 Floors)    3 See Dimensions

Bedrooms    Bathrooms   Super area  Floor   Status

1   1   520 4 (Out of 40 Floors)    1
```

In the `Status` column i am getting wrong value.

I have tried:

```
    # Go through of them and click on each.
        for unique_link in my_needed_links:
            unique_link.click()

            time.sleep(2)
            driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])

            def get_elements_by_xpath(driver, xpath):
                return [entry.text for entry in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)]


            search_entries = [
            ("Bedrooms", "//div[@class='seeBedRoomDimen']"),
            ("Bathrooms", "//div[@class='p_value']"),
            ("Super area", "//span[@id='coveredAreaDisplay']"),
            ("Floor", "//div[@class='p_value truncated']"),
            ("Lift", "//div[@class='p_value']")]

            with open('textfile.csv', 'a+') as f_output:
                csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
                # Write header
                csv_output.writerow([name for name, xpath in search_entries])
                entries = []
                for name, xpath in search_entries:
                    entries.append(get_elements_by_xpath(driver, xpath))
                csv_output.writerows(zip(*entries))

            get_elements_by_xpath(driver, xpath)
```

**Edit**

Entries: as list

```
[['3 See Dimensions'], ['3 See Dimensions', '4', '3', '1', '2100 sqft', '1400 sqft', '33%', 'Avenue 54', 'Under Construction', "Dec, '20", 'New Property', '₹ 7.90 Cr ₹ 39,50,000 Approx. Registration Charges ₹ 15 Per sq. Unit Monthly\nSee Other Charges', "Santacruz West, Mumbai., Santacruz West, Mumbai - Western Suburbs, Maharashtra What's Nearby", "Next To St Teresa's Convent School & Sacred Heart School on SV Road.", 'East', 'P51800007149 (The project has been registered via MahaRERA registration number: P51800007149 and is available on the website https://maharera.mahaonline.gov.in under registered projects.)', 'Garden/Park, Pool, Main Road', 'Marble, Marbonite, Wooden', '1 Covered', '24 Hours Available', 'No/Rare Powercut', '6', '6', 'Unfurnished', 'Municipal Corporation of Greater Mumbai', 'Freehold', 'Brokers please do not contact', ''], ['2100'], ['7 (Out of 23 Floors)'], ['3 See Dimensions', '4', '3', '1', '2100 sqft', '1400 sqft', '33%', 'Avenue 54 1 Discussion on forum', 'Under Construction', "Dec, '20", 'New Property', '₹ 7.90 Cr ₹ 39,50,000 Approx. Registration Charges ₹ 15 Per sq. Unit Monthly\nSee Other Charges', "Santacruz West, Mumbai., Santacruz West, Mumbai - Western Suburbs, Maharashtra What's Nearby", "Next To St Teresa's Convent School & Sacred Heart School on SV Road.", 'East', 'P51800007149 (The project has been registered via MahaRERA registration number: P51800007149 and is available on the website https://maharera.mahaonline.gov.in under registered projects.)', 'Garden/Park, Pool, Main Road', 'Marble, Marbonite, Wooden', '1 Covered', '24 Hours Available', 'No/Rare Powercut', '6', '6', 'Unfurnished', 'Municipal Corporation of Greater Mumbai', 'Freehold', 'Brokers please do not contact', '']]
[['3 See Dimensions'], ['3 See Dimensions', '4', '3', '1', '2100 sqft', '1400 sqft', '33%', 'Avenue 54 1 Discussion on forum', 'Under Construction', "Dec, '20", 'New Property', '₹ 7.90 Cr ₹ 39,50,000 Approx. Registration Charges ₹ 15 Per sq. Unit Monthly\nSee Other Charges', "Santacruz West, Mumbai., Santacruz West, Mumbai - Western Suburbs, Maharashtra What's Nearby", "Next To St Teresa's Convent School & Sacred Heart School on SV Road.", 'East', 'P51800007149 (The project has been registered via MahaRERA registration number: P51800007149 and is available on the website https://maharera.mahaonline.gov.in under registered projects.)', 'Garden/Park, Pool, Main Road', 'Marble, Marbonite, Wooden', '1 Covered', '24 Hours Available', 'No/Rare Powercut', '6', '6', 'Unfurnished', 'Municipal Corporation of Greater Mumbai', 'Freehold', 'Brokers please do not contact', ''], ['2100'], ['7 (Out of 23 Floors)'], ['3 See Dimensions', '4', '3', '1', '2100 sqft', '1400 sqft', '33%', 'Avenue 54 1 Discussion on forum', 'Under Construction', "Dec, '20", 'New Property', '₹ 7.90 Cr ₹ 39,50,000 Approx. Registration Charges ₹ 15 Per sq. Unit Monthly\nSee Other Charges', "Santacruz West, Mumbai., Santacruz West, Mumbai - Western Suburbs, Maharashtra What's Nearby", "Next To St Teresa's Convent School & Sacred Heart School on SV Road.", 'East', 'P51800007149 (The project has been registered via MahaRERA registration number: P51800007149 and is available on the website https://maharera.mahaonline.gov.in under registered projects.)', 'Garden/Park, Pool, Main Road', 'Marble, Marbonite, Wooden', '1 Covered', '24 Hours Available', 'No/Rare Powercut', '6', '6', 'Unfurnished', 'Municipal Corporation of Greater Mumbai', 'Freehold', 'Brokers please do not contact', '']]
```

website link: `https://www.magicbricks.com/propertyDetails/1-BHK-520-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Kandivali-West-in-Mumbai&id=4d423333373433343431`

**Edit 1**

```
my_needed_links = []

list_links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")

for i in range(0, 2):
    # Get unique links.
    for link in list_links:
        if "https://www.magicbricks.com/propertyDetails/" in link.get_attribute("href"):
            if link not in my_needed_links:
                my_needed_links.append(link)

    # Go through of them and click on each.
        for unique_link in my_needed_links:
            unique_link.click()

            time.sleep(2)
            driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])

            def get_elements_by_xpath(driver, xpath):
                return [entry.text for entry in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)]

            search_entries = [
            ("Bedrooms", "//div[@class='seeBedRoomDimen']"),
            ("Bathrooms", "//div[@class='p_value']"),
            ("Super area", "//span[@id='coveredAreaDisplay']"),
            ("Floor", "//div[@class='p_value truncated']"),
            ("Lift", "//div[@class='p_value']")]

            #with open('textfile.csv', 'a+') as f_output:
            entries = []
            for name, xpath in search_entries:
                entries.append(get_elements_by_xpath(driver, xpath))
                data = [entry for entry in entries if len(entry)==28]
                df = pd.DataFrame(data)
                print (df)
            df.to_csv('nameoffile.csv', mode='a',index=False,encoding='utf-8')
            #df.to_csv('nameoffile.csv',mode='a', index=False,encoding='utf-8')

            get_elements_by_xpath(driver, xpath)
            time.sleep(2)

            driver.close()
            # Switch back to the main tab/window.
            driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

Thank you in advance. Please suggest something

Comment: Why are you defining a function in a loop? Is it possible to share sample data entries? Or better the website your trying to get data from so to offer a way to structure your data?

Comment: @Prayson Daniel, Just edited question. Please check

Comment: specify `newline` as in : `with open('textfile.csv', 'a+', newline = "") as f_output:` might help as well - [doku](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer)

Comment: @Patrick Artner, not working, getting same output

Answer (score 0):

I could not load the page due to my location. But from your entries, you could do:

```
 #Your selenium imports
import pandas as pd

def get_elements_by_xpath(driver, xpath):
    return [entry.text for entry in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)]


for unique_link in my_needed_links:
    unique_link.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
    search_entries = [
        ("Bedrooms", "//div[@class='seeBedRoomDimen']"), ("Bathrooms", "//div[@class='p_value']"),("Super area", "//span[@id='coveredAreaDisplay']"),("Floor", "//div[@class='p_value truncated']"),("Lift", "//div[@class='p_value']")]

    entries = []
    for name, xpath in search_entries:
        entries.append(get_elements_by_xpath(driver, xpath))

    data = [entry for entry in entries if len(entry)>5]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

    df.to_csv('nameoffile.csv', sep=';',index=False,encoding='utf-8',mode='a')

    get_elements_by_xpath(driver, xpath)
```

Comment: Please explain about this line:  `[entry for entry in entries if len(entry)>5]` and why we are using 5?

Comment: You could use 4,6,any number less than your complete minded columns. I noted that your entries had at index 1 and 4, complete data. 0, 2, and 3 has part of the data containing already in 1. The pattern was that if the elements number of was less than a certain threshold, disregard.

Comment: Just check the length is 28. I have update the answer to be specific.

Comment: All page data is not the same format. Means all pages do not have column 28.

Comment: It does not depend on data found, as empty strings are counted. What results do you have after trying this method?

Comment: I just sharing a link of result getting `https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aRLhQM4UuOulJ9LobPkXOERCMAzAGQYw`. Why am I getting duplicate values?

Comment: I am not sure. It appears that you are looping same. Can you update your script, so I can see what’s going on?

Comment: I have coded blind :) as I am not sure what you get. Can you try the updated script above?

Comment: What results do you get now?

Comment: Getting error: `StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)`

Answer (score 0):

The xpath for bathrooms and for lift are the same, therefore you get the same results in these columns. Try to find another way to identify and distinguish between them. You can probably use an index, though if there's another way it's usually preferred.